# Is this the "right" way to call for a txt file in php

Tags: php

so I'm working on a php example and the solution I've come up with works. I'm just not sure if it's the "best way" or maybe the "right way" to do it.

I'm making a guest book the html and the first php is provided:

HTML:

```
<h2>Enter your name to sign our guest book</h2>

<form method="POST" action="SignGuestBook.php">

    <p>First Name <input type="text" name="first_name"/></p>
    <p>Last Name <input type="text" name="last_name"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
    
</form>

<p><a href="ShowGuestBook.php">Show Guest Book</a></p>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST['first_name']) || empty ($_POST['last_name']))
    echo "<p>You must enter your first and last name.
            Click your browser's back button to return to the Guest Book.</p>\n";

else {
    $FirstName = addslashes($_POST['first_name']);
    $LastName = addslashes($_POST['last_name']);
    $GuestBook = fopen("guestbook.txt", "ab");
    if (is_writeable("guestbook.txt")) {
        if (fwrite($GuestBook, $LastName . ", " . $FirstName . "\n"))
            echo "<p>Thank you for signing our guest book!</p>\n";
        else
            echo "<p>Cannot add your name to the guest.<p>";
    }
    else 
        echo "<p>Cannot write to the file.<p>\n";
    fclose($GuestBook);
    }
?>
```

So here, i'm clicking to see who signed the guest book and displaying the txt contents. Everything works perfectly, my solution just feels too simple (maybe). Since I'm still learning, I'd rather learn how to do something the right or better way. So if I should approach this differently, please let me know:

```
 <?php

  echo "<pre>";
  readfile("guestbook.txt");
  echo "</pre>";

  ?>
```

Comment: Is there a problem here? If your code works and you want a code review, ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thanks, i'll ask there. I didn't know about that thread.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular oh no, this Code Review craziness again. This is not a code for review, the OP is asking for the potential problems of a simple scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem of your code is potential loss of clarity which one is the first name and which one is the last name. You save it as `{first name},{last name}`, but what if I put a comma there in my first or last name?

I'd suggest using a well-known format such as CSV or JSON, which solve problems like this.

I'd go with JSON, which is very easy to work with in PHP:

```php
$data = [
    'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
];

$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

file_put_contents('guestbook.json', $json);
```

Then, you can retrieve your data by doing the opposite:

```php
$json = file_get_contents('guestbook.json');
$data = json_decode($json, true); // true makes it an array
```

Also, please notice how I'm simply using `file_put_contents()`. It's a one-liner for putting contents into a file in PHP.

Comment: thanks for this! I don't really know much about JSON yet, but cool to see how they can work together

Comment: @coolcoolcool it's worth it reading about JSON, as this format is a pleasure to work with and it's the single most common data format among modern APIs! :)